# Swift get ip address of computer with specific ip address (127.0.0.1). NetService NetServiceBrowser

Tags: swift

I am trying to get the port number of a service running on the network. Mainly I only want the port number for the service running on the local machine (loopback address).
I have 3 computers running the same service and I am getting the port number for all machines. I only want to get the port number for the machine running with loopback address. Example port number for computer with address 127.0.0.1

```
 func netServiceDidResolveAddress(_ sender: NetService) {
        if let addresses = sender.addresses {
            for data in addresses {
                let family: sa_family_t = data.withUnsafeBytes { rawBufferPointer in
                    let socketAddress = rawBufferPointer.bindMemory(to: sockaddr.self).baseAddress?.pointee
                    return socketAddress?.sa_family ?? sa_family_t(0)
                }

                if family == sa_family_t(AF_INET) {
                    let port = data.withUnsafeBytes { rawBufferPointer -> Int? in
                        guard let sockaddrPtr = rawBufferPointer.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: sockaddr_in.self) else {
                            return nil
                        }
                        return Int(UInt16(bigEndian: sockaddrPtr.pointee.sin_port))
                    }
                    if let port = port {
                        print("Service Port: \(port)")
                    }
                } else if family == sa_family_t(AF_INET6) {
                    let port = data.withUnsafeBytes { rawBufferPointer -> Int? in
                        guard let sockaddrPtr = rawBufferPointer.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: sockaddr_in6.self) else {
                            return nil
                        }
                        return Int(UInt16(bigEndian: sockaddrPtr.pointee.sin6_port))
                    }
                    if let port = port {
                        print("Service Port: \(port)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```